# How to compare posterior distributions for different observed data? KL-divergence?

Tags: bayesian, error, kullback-leibler, inverse-problem

So I'm solving an inverse problem with the Bayesian approach
$p(u | y) \propto p(y| u )p(u)$.

Assuming I have two datasets $y_1$ and $y_2$, what can be said about the difference in the posteriors $p(u | y_1)$ and $p(u | y_2)$? Can I use Kullback-Leibler divergence for this?
(the datasets are assumed to be samples from the same probability distribution)

Also, is there a name for this kind of error type in Bayesian modeling? I quess this problem must be explained somewhere but it seems I'm not searching for the right expressions...

Comment: In what way is this "inverse"?

Comment: It is inverse because there is a relation $y = G(u)$ between the data $y$ and the parameter $u$ and I'm estimating the parameter from the data. It maybe does not matter for the question if the problem is inverse, though

Comment: I've edited your title to better reflect the question, please feel free to roll it back or change it if this is inaccurate.

Comment: Also, you may want to read up on [sensitivity analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_analysis) and its use in [Bayesian methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_Bayesian_analysis#Sensitivity_analysis). (I've usually heard the term refer to analyzing different priors, but you might find the concepts helpful.)

Comment: I've come across it, but so far all I saw in this context was along the lines of different priors or different likelihoods (for the same data).